# Is it possible to inline a lambda expression?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, inline, inlining

I want to inline a lambda expression since it is very short for performance reason. Is it possible?

Comment: Since the function is defined in the class definition, it's `inline` by default anyway.

Comment: dup: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15930755/86967

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `inline` keyword does not actually cause functions to be inlined. Any recent compiler is going to make better decisions with regards to inlining than you will.

In the case of a short lambda, the function will probably be inlined.

If you're trying to use the `inline` keyword with a lambda, the answer is no, you can't use that.

Comment: It is trivially easy to come up with counterexamples to the claim that a recent compiler will make better decisions about in-lining than a given human will.  I am not a C guru at all yet when I have had speed critical code, tagging a method with an inline hint often produces a faster executable. All one has to do is measure the code.  I would advise anyone who has been told that the compiler knows better to set up a test bed where they can time various functions with and without inline hints to explore when you can outsmart the compiler.

Comment: @jack Of course. But you need things like __declspec(forceinline) or __declspec(noinline) to do that. If doing that makes any measurable improvement, 1. you need more LTO / LTCG, 2. you need more PGO, or 3. compiler bugs. Compilers don't do everything people claim that they do all the time, but inlining is one of those areas where they are generally really really good.

Answer (score 15):

The compiler will inline it if it can. For example, in g++ 4.5 with -O2,

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main () {
    std::vector<int> a(10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++ i) a[i] = i;

    asm ("Ltransform_begin: nop; nop; nop; nop; nop; nop; ");
    std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), a.begin(), [] (int x) { return 2*x; });
    asm ("Lforeach_begin: nop; nop; nop; nop; nop; nop; ");
    std::for_each(a.begin(), a.end(), [] (int x) { printf("%d\n", x); });
    asm ("Lforeach_done: nop; nop; nop; nop; nop; nop; ");

    return 0;
}
```

generates the assembly that the `2*x` and `printf` lambdas are completely inlined.

```
# 9 "x.cpp" 1
    Ltransform_begin: nop; nop; nop; nop; nop; nop; 
# 0 "" 2
    .align 4,0x90
L13:
    sall    (%rax)
    addq    $4, %rax
    cmpq    %rax, %r12
    jne L13
# 13 "x.cpp" 1
    Lforeach_begin: nop; nop; nop; nop; nop; nop; 
# 0 "" 2
    .align 4,0x90
L14:
    movl    (%rbx), %esi
    leaq    LC0(%rip), %rdi
    xorl    %eax, %eax
LEHB1:
    call    _printf
LEHE1:
    addq    $4, %rbx
    cmpq    %r12, %rbx
    jne L14
# 17 "x.cpp" 1
    Lforeach_done: nop; nop; nop; nop; nop; nop; 
# 0 "" 2
```

Answer (score 9):

It is possible that a lambda expression might be inlined.  Under the hood, a lambda expression is no different than any other function object.

Whether a particular lambda expression is inlined is entirely dependent upon the compiler and whether it decides it is worth inlining.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a regular struct functor, the compiler will almost certainly inline it. If you have a C++0x style lambda, the compiler will almost certainly inline it. If you're using a boost::lambda, then it might do, depending on how the lambda works underneath the scenes. Short version: You can't guarantee it's inlining or non-inlining, but you should trust your compiler and if in doubt, make it easy and simple to inline.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked at the output from a *lot* of them by any means, but so far all of them I've looked at the output from have been inlined.

Answer (score 0):

C++1x' lambdas will, under the hood, generate normal function objects. Those can be inlined by the compiler.

Did any measurements you made suggest the compiler did not inline them in a place where this leads to a notable performance loss?

Comment: Nitpick: No work on C++1x has started yet, and it's nothing more than an educated guess that there even will be a C++1x. The committee is still working on C++0x, and it's not likely that the working title will be changed, just because it won't match the final short title of the standard.

Comment: @Christopher: I disagree. It's likely that the next C++ standard will be C++11, it might become C++12, it's unlikely to become C++10, and impossible to become C++09. Since the last (and only the last) digit is uncertain, it's commonly replaced by an `x`. Whether it will have lambdas is certainly not guaranteed (just look at consepts), but it's __very__ unlikely the committee would settle for anything less.

Comment: The joke is that the 0x is hex now, as most people continue to use C++0x